# MySQL GROUP BY ORDER по последним в GROUP BY значениям

Tags: mysql, group-by, order

Есть таблица "криптовалют" (последнее поле пусть будет время):

```
CREATE TABLE orders (id INT, name VARCHAR (100), rank INT, tm INT);
    INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,'BTC', 0, 15040),
                                    (2,'ETH', 1, 15040),
                                    (3,'BTN', 2, 15040),
                                    (4,'RPL', 3, 15040),
                                    (5,'BTC', 0, 15102),
                                    (6,'ETH', 2, 15102),
                                    (7,'BTN', 3, 15102),
                                    (8,'RPL', 1, 15102);
```

И есть вывод из нее:

```
SELECT id, name, rank,
       substr(min(concat(lpad(id,10,'0'),rank)),11)-
       substr(max(concat(lpad(id,10,'0'),rank)),11) diff
  FROM orders GROUP BY name ORDER BY rank
```

Но мне нужна сортировка по последним значениям 'rank', то есть вывод в таком порядке:

```
BTC (0)
RPL (1)
ETH (2)
BTN (3)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db4675/4)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db4675/8 - такой вариант выводит, как задумано, однако разницу не считает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без извращений с конкатенацией:

```
SELECT max_id, o1.name, last_rank,
       first_rank-last_rank AS diff
  FROM ( 
         SELECT max(id) AS max_id, min(id) AS min_id, name
            FROM orders
            GROUP BY name
       ) AS o1
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT id, rank AS last_rank
            FROM orders
       ) AS o2
         ON o2.id=max_id
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT id, rank AS first_rank
            FROM orders
       ) AS o3
         ON o3.id=min_id
  ORDER BY last_rank;
```

Второй вариант, без подзапросов в `JOIN`'ах

```
SELECT max_id, last.name, last.rank,
       first.rank-last.rank AS diff
  FROM (
         SELECT max(id) AS max_id, min(id) AS min_id
            FROM orders
            GROUP BY name
       ) AS o
       INNER JOIN orders AS last ON last.id=max_id
       INNER JOIN orders AS first ON first.id=min_id
  ORDER BY last.rank;
```

Comment: Сэр, более 2 500 000 строк в таблице.

Comment: @ChooHwan и как, сильно медленнее получается? я надеюсь в реальной таблице id — PK... а если добавить индекс (name, id) [или хотя бы просто name]?

Comment: Я очень Вам благодарен за ответы и участие. Спасибо. А в таблице 10 полей и все их нужно выводить. Каждый дополнительный SELECT - значительно увеличивает время. Как бы хостер не начал прессовать за перебор памяти.

Comment: @ChooHwan, мне действительно было бы интересно узнать, есть ли разница в тайминге и/или в памяти... если id — `INT` `PRIMARY_KEY` и `AUTO_INCRMENT`, то по идее `JOIN`'ы для каждого элемента должен был бы выполняться за O(1), а индексы по name'у и/или (name, id) значительно ускорить группировку и поиск максимума/минимума, что в лучшем случае должно дать время выполнения запроса O(N*log(N)), где N — количество различных значений name... дополнительного использования памяти при любом количестве полей я тут не вижу (по крайней мере не более, чем двукратное)...

Comment: Запрос возможно будет работать быстрее, если заменить второй и третий `SELECT`'ы на `JOIN`'ы напрямую с orders.

Comment: Я, извините, не понял, каким образом это сделать?

Comment: @ChooHwan, добавил вариантом...

Comment: спасибо! Я проверю Ваш код сразу на проекте.

Comment: Колоссальный "привес" к скорости! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Наверное будет так:

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, o.rank, tmp.diff       
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, max(tm) as tm, 
            SUBSTR(MIN(CONCAT(LPAD(id,10,'0'),rank)),11)- SUBSTR(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(id,10,'0'),rank)),11) diff 
            FROM orders 
            GROUP BY name
          ) tmp
ON tmp.name = o.name
WHERE o.tm = tmp.tm
ORDER BY o.rank
```

То есть во внутреннем запросе выбираем имя, максимальное `tm` и разницу с группировкой, а во внешнем объединяем по имени беря параллельно `diff`

Comment: You're genius!! Thank You!!

Comment: @ChooHwan на всякий случай потестируй на разных данных))

Comment: Боюсь. Там 2500000 строк.

Comment: @ChooHwan ну не всех) часть выбрать, чтоб точно убедиться в правильности))

Comment: Сейчас отпишусь.

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, 
   (SELECT r.rank FROM orders r WHERE r.name = o.name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as NewRank,
   substr(min(concat(lpad(o.id,10,'0'),o.rank)),11)-
   substr(max(concat(lpad(o.id,10,'0'),o.rank)),11) diff
FROM orders o GROUP BY o.name ORDER BY NewRank ASC
```

Comment: Ух ты!! Даже инкремент сохранен!! Тоже спасибо большое!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db4675/78

Comment: 78 секунд выборка.

Comment: Индексы поставьте, даже на большой таблице должно выполняться за несколько секунд. Обязательно индексы: id и name.

Comment: Уже поздно. Не обрабатывает UPDATE. Я хотел дополнительное поле сделать, чтобы ренк (в этом поле) у всех видов валют обновлялся на последний. Ну, если RPL стал = 1, то по всей таблице в этом дополнительном поле у всех RPL поменялось на 1. Запрос выполняется 2 минуты и возвращается без ошибки пустым.